# C# WebAPI: Set default JSON serializer to NewtonSoft JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a very simply WebAPI in .Net 4.6.
WebAPI, by default use JSON.Net as JSON serializer.
For this application, I am willing to set default JSON serializer to NewtonSoft JSON.

Please help me how I can do this.

Comment: JSON.Net is NewtonSoft's JSON serializer. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm

Comment: Agree. Thanks @MurrayFoxcroft

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```

Would be placed in your `global.asax.cs` file.

Comment: Yes, this is working for me. JSON.Net was failing while deserialization as from client I am sending data that is serialized using Newtonsoft.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!