# Custom JsonConverter not working on WebAPI object deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a model object that I send to the browser and gets sent back to me.  I want that ID value in that object to be encrypted.  I created a custom JsonConverter to encrypt the string and then decrypt it.

```
public class SecretItem
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EncryptedIdConverter))]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is my EncryptedIdConverter class

```
class EncryptedIdConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string encryptedValue = (string)value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encryptedValue))
            encryptedValue = Encryption.EncryptString(encryptedValue);

        serializer.Serialize(writer, encryptedValue);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string decryptedString = (string)reader.Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(decryptedString))
            decryptedString = Encryption.DecryptString(decryptedString);

        return decryptedString;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

If I try calling the JsonConvert.Serialization functions, everything works correctly.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(secretItem)
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SecretItem>([JSON secretItem]);
```

When I return the `HttpActionResult Ok(secretItem)`... the browser also gets the encrypted Id string.

However, when I POST the data back to my controller, my webapi method is not getting a decrypted property.  It skips the JsonConverter.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(SecretItem secretItem)
{
    // Not decrypted
    var decryptedId = secretItem.Id;
}
```

Why would the deserialize logic not be working the same as the serialize logic in my WebAPI?  I don't even know where to start debugging that.

We are using Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0.0, MVC5, .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Have you tried break-pointing your custom converter to make sure it's getting called?

Comment: Yes. It gets called when I call JsonConvert directly.  And it gets called during the serialization in WebAPI.  I don't know why it is skipped during deserialization in the WebAPI.

Comment: what is your CanConvert method ?

Comment: I added  my EncryptedIdConverter class to the original post, since it was too long to add as a comment.

Comment: @MohamedElrashid When I added a breakpoint, I don't see the CanConvert method getting called during any of my serialization... when I return it from a controller and it gets serialized or when I call JsonConvert.De/SerializeObject directly.

Comment: I think you need to tell Web API that its serializer should make use of that converter.  Add it to the serializer's `Converters` collection in your global.asax.

Comment: @Amy I did try that and I think it got called for all string values then.

Comment: When I put a breakpoint in Newtonsoft's JsonSerializer, I don't even see the deserialize logic being called when my http request comes in.  Maybe WebAPI doesn't call that for simple objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the code is working correctly. The problem was that on the POST that was being tested, the content-type wasn't set to "application/json".  So, it didn't use the JsonNetFormatter and therefore skipped the converter.

Once I set the contentType, everything works!

Answer (score 2):

How is your Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
  FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

it should work

### maybe you need a TypeConverter

### Model binding

> When Web API calls a method on a controller, it must set values for the parameters, a process called binding

- This is called **Model binding**

  ```
   Post(SecretItem secretItem)
  ```
- Model binding use a TypeConverter

### JSON Serialization

- This is called **JSON Serialization**

  ```
  HttpActionResult Ok(secretItem)
  ```
- JSON Serialization use a JsonConverter

### Documentation

- [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)
- [JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

### more

- [asp.net mvc - C# WebAPI: Set default JSON serializer to NewtonSoft JSON - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718964/c-sharp-webapi-set-default-json-serializer-to-newtonsoft-json)
- [c# - Setting the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750/setting-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [c# - How to use Json.NET for JSON modelbinding in an MVC5 project? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995210/how-to-use-json-net-for-json-modelbinding-in-an-mvc5-project)